# chrpath for Cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, gnu

Is there a chrpath binary for Cygwin?

I've tried compiling it and was met wit this error:

```
./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
[...]
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating deb/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
Configure status:
-----------------
 CC     = gcc
 CFLAGS = -g -O2 -W -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wcomments -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wstrict-prototypes
 LDRPATH= -R 

+ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_Sandbox/chrpath-0.16'
Making all in testsuite
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_Sandbox/chrpath-0.16/testsuite'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'prog.exe', needed by 'all-am'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_Sandbox/chrpath-0.16/testsuite'
Makefile:487: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_Sandbox/chrpath-0.16'
Makefile:294: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the source of prog.exe error? Do you know where I can look?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's something to do with the Makefile rule for generating the executable doesn't properly take into account that Cygwin requires .exe at the end of an executable.

The package manager should take a look at autoconf tools and how they should work on Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

consider `make -k -j` and `make -k -j install` because it does not seem that the target prog.exe in testsuite directory is important